# Jump once only until character lands

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I just started using Unity am trying to make a simple 3D platformer, before I can get to that, I need to get movement down. My problem comes in when the player jumps. When they jump, they can jump in the air as much as they want. I want it to only jump once. Can anybody help?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start ()   
    }

        void Update()
        {
            bool player_jump = Input.GetButtonDown("DefaultJump");
            if (player_jump)
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 365f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a flag to detect when the player is touching the ground then only jump the player is touching the floor. This can be set to `true` and `false` in the `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` functions.

Create a tag named "Ground" and make the GameObjects use this tag then attach the modified code below to the player that is doing the jumping.

```
private Rigidbody rb;
bool isGrounded = true;
public float jumpForce = 20f;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    bool player_jump = Input.GetButtonDown("DefaultJump");

    if (player_jump && isGrounded)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}


void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

---

Sometimes, using `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` may not be fast enough. This is rare but possible. If you run into this then use Raycast with `Physics.Raycast` to detect the floor. Make sure to throw the ray to the "Ground" layer only.

```
private Rigidbody rb;
public float jumpForce = 20f;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    bool player_jump = Input.GetButtonDown("DefaultJump");

    if (player_jump && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
    }
}

bool IsGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    float raycastDistance = 10;
    //Raycast to to the floor objects only
    int mask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground");

    //Raycast downwards
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit,
        raycastDistance, mask))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out! At first I didn't know how to add a tag, but I just looked through the settings. Thanks so much this really helped!.